# Sending textbox inputs to email HTML

Tags: html, forms, email, textbox

I'm working on a page where I have 2 textboxes.
I want to send the user inputs for these 2 mailboxes to my email but my code doesn't seem to work. Is there anything I've missed?

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com" >
First:<input type="text" name="First" size="12" maxlength="12" />
Last:<input type="text" name="Last" size="24" maxlength="24" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, it does work for me. It probably doesn't work for you because you don't have an email client, or your browser turns off this feature for security (or something like that). I would recommend that you use a service to perform this action such as http://www.braveapps.com/emailfwd/ or http://allforms.mailjol.net/.